# How to reset the socket adress use in python ? ( solve WinError 10048 )

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

after creating a little pygame program, I wish to make it multiplayer friendly, with a possibility to play locally. My aim is to allow two independent players in my world!

So, I've basically tried to learn how to use the socket module of python.

Okay, let's go in, my first attempt was to connect a client on a basic server.

I follow a very nice tutorial and get a final code based on this structure :

```py
#server.py

import socket
from threading import Thread

class Serv(Thread):


    def __init__(self, conn):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.conn = conn

    def run(self):
        data = self.conn.recv(1024)
        data = data.decode("utf8")
        print(data)


host, port = ('', 8486)

socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.bind((host, port))

run = True

while run :
    socket.listen(5)
    conn, adress = socket.accept()

    thread_serv = Serv(conn)
    thread_serv.start()
conn.close()
socket.close()
```

And :

```py
#client.py

import socket

host, port = ('localhost', 8486)



try:
    socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    socket.connect((host, port))
    print("You're in !")

    data = "bonjour"
    data = data.encode("utf8")
    socket.sendall(data)

except ConnectionRefusedError:
    print("There is no server to join !")
except :
    print("connexion lost...")
finally:
    socket.close()
```

The first time I run these two programs ( first server.py and then client.py ), everything works perfectly.

But when I run it a second time, the console returns me :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Cédric\Documents\logiciels\python\By Edhyjox\Tower\bin\serveur.py", line 20, in <module>
    socket.bind((host, port))
OSError: [WinError 10048] Une seule utilisation de chaque adresse de socket (protocole/adresse réseau/port) est habituellement autorisée
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

if I translate you the last line, it's deal with something like this :
`Only one use of each socket address ( protocol/network address/port) is usually allowed`

I know it's come from the port because when I change it, it's working again till I don't use two times the same port.

But Is there a way to reset all used port and make it again usable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code tries to call `listen` multiple times. This is wrong. `listen` is expected to be called once, only `accept` has to be called for each new connection. Your code should be:

```
...
socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.bind((host, port))
socket.listen(5)

run = True

while run :
    conn, adress = socket.accept()

    thread_serv = Serv(conn)
    thread_serv.start()
conn.close()
socket.close()
```